# Have a VStack with a square background depending on its content in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, layout

I'm running into a kind of a conundrum with a seemingly simple problem...

My view has a content with a smaller width than height, and I wish to have it displayed within a nice square card.

Here's what I've done here:

```
struct SquareView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .font(.system(size: 100))
                .padding()
                .foregroundColor(.red)
            Text("Yo !")
                .font(.title)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .foregroundColor(.orange)
        }
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill) // Same result with or without this line
        .padding()
        .background(Color.white.opacity(0.5))
        .cornerRadius(16)
    }
}

struct SquareView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SquareView()
            .padding(30)
            .background(.yellow)
    }
}
```

But the `aspectRatio` bit seems to have absolutely no effect on the square part I wish to achieve.

[image: First attempt]

After looking up for a solution, it seems that `ZStack` was to be my savior...

Ok, then, here's what I did, and I almost succeeded:

```
struct SquareView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(Color.white.opacity(0.5))
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .cornerRadius(16)
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: "globe")
                    .font(.system(size: 100))
                    .padding()
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                Text("Yo !")
                    .font(.title)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .foregroundColor(.orange)
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .fixedSize()
    }
}
```

And lo!

[image: Second attempt]

It's square, all right, but the size of the `ZStack` does not seem to take into account the `Rectangle`, as it is confirmed when it is selected in Xcode:

[image: ZStack selection]

So the only solution seems to be one involving `GeometryReader` and pride makes me refuse this remain of the old age!

I'm sure, someone out there knows there is another way, I'm certain to be quite close... Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:** I've put the whole file in the example, instead of just the content.

**EDIT 2:** Here's the complete solution for my example thanks to @Paulw11's answer.

```
struct SquareView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .font(.system(size: 100))
                .padding()
                .foregroundColor(.red)
            Text("Yo !")
                .font(.title)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .foregroundColor(.orange)
        }
        .padding()
        .background {
            Rectangle()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .foregroundColor(.white.opacity(0.5))
                .cornerRadius(16)
        }
    }
}
```

And its result:
[image]

Comment: provided code does... nothing?

Comment: Just put the code in the body of a SwiftUI View to see it.

Comment: @GrandSirr, I edited the post to put the whole file in the example, instead of just the content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply set a background for your existing content and give it a negative inset:

```
struct CardView: View {
    var body: some View {
       ContentView()
          .background(
               Rectangle()
                .inset(by:-30)
                .aspectRatio(1.0, contentMode:.fill)
                .foregroundColor(.yellow)
          ) 
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I see two problems. First, and the biggest, the card is not a square… the second is that the 30 padding was just an example for the preview, whenever I use my view I don’t know what would be the padding of the parent…

Comment: Sorry I misread your answer as I was looking for the light card to be square... That's the correct answer.